# Can groovy run javascript?

Tags: javascript, groovy

I'm a newbie in groovy and javascript. I'm trying to make a groovy script that runs a javascript in it.

Is it possible for groovy to run a javascript on its class? If it is possible, then how can a groovy script run a javascript?

Some sample syntax will be a big help!

Comment: I changed your title and question-text from 'java script' to 'javascript'. Note that javascript has nothing to do with Java (although there are javascript-engines for Java).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the javascript code you want to run.
If your javascript only involves some basic operations etc, you could use ScriptEngieManager, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html

Just include the library at the beginning of your groovy script:

```
import javax.script.*
```

If your javascript code involves DOM manipulation and/or stuff that has to do with a browser to function properly, you'll need a java-based browser like htmlUnit: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: so i need to download a htmlUnit??

Comment: Yes, and add it to classpath.